# SharePoint 2013 - Add to list but no viewing

Tags: listview, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create a list that everyone can add to, but cannot view others submissions and an admin team can manage all.

I thought about doing this with the list view default to only show created by [Me] and then having an admin page with the list web part and a different view showing all. This doesn't prevent the users from changing the view though.

I then looked into hiding a view, or preventing users from selecting it but I came up with nothing at the end of that as well.

So what is a good way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list item level permissions:

http://www.onlysharepoint2013.com/2013/04/set-item-level-permission-in-sharepoint.html

or you can create list item even reciever and setup there permission for each item.

Comment: Thanks for this. I changed those settings previously, as I thought they would do what I needed. It turns out my test account had elevated rights embedded elsewhere. You suggesting this made me look further into it and you're right. This does the trick.